# "Did not get reply from planning scene client" when using CollisionModelsInterface

Tags: ros, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have found that if a node creates a planning_environment::CollisionModelsInterface object and also calls the /environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff service, the service always reports that it is unable to get a reply from planning scene client with the name of the node.  Specifically, if I run the pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch file and this piece of test code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "planning_scene_test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::ServiceClient scene_client =
    n.serviceClient
    ("/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff");
  ROS_INFO("Waiting for planning scene service");
  scene_client.waitForExistence();
  ROS_INFO("Planning scene service is now available");
  
  planning_environment::CollisionModelsInterface cmi("robot_description");
  arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff ssd;
  if (!scene_client.call(ssd)) {
    ROS_ERROR("Unable to set planning scene");
    return 1;
  }
  ROS_INFO("Successfully set planning scene");
  return 0;
}
```

the execution will pause for five seconds during the scene_client call and print the following to rosout:

```
[ INFO] [1322764074.606153612, 4535.143000000]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /planning_scene_test_node
[ INFO] [1322764080.585060399, 4540.165000000]: Did not get reply from planning scene client /planning_scene_test_node.  Incrementing counter to 1
```

The collision models interface declared within this node also does not update to the new planning scene and has to be set manually.

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS electric.  The version of the arm_navigation stack is 1.0.7-s1321929829~lucid.

Thanks,

Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12147/%22did-not-get-reply-from-planning-scene-client%22-when-using-collisionmodelsinterface/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2011-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You aren't calling ros::spin anywhere and the main thread of the program is blocking so the necessary callbacks aren't ever occurring.  Adding an AsynSpinner is the right way to go. This code works for me:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <arm_navigation_msgs/SetPlanningSceneDiff.h>
#include <planning_environment/models/collision_models_interface.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "planning_scene_test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1); 
  spinner.start();

  ros::ServiceClient scene_client =
    n.serviceClient<arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff>
    ("/environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff");
  ROS_INFO("Waiting for planning scene service");
  scene_client.waitForExistence();
  ROS_INFO("Planning scene service is now available");

  planning_environment::CollisionModelsInterface cmi("robot_description");
  arm_navigation_msgs::SetPlanningSceneDiff ssd;
  if (!scene_client.call(ssd)) {
    ROS_ERROR("Unable to set planning scene");
    return 1;
  }
  ROS_INFO("Successfully set planning scene");
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on 2011-12-01**:
Oh, of course.  Thank you.  It's working for me too now.